# Can you open the Option Menu from a button?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I have a Option Menu that opens when I'm clicking the menu button on a android smartphone. And I wonder if there is some way to call the onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected method from a onClick method for a button. So when I click on a button in my app instead of clicking the menu button on the smartphone.

Comment: You should not recreate something that's already in the system and working. User expects the menu button and will use it which makes your extra button useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke [`Activity.openOptionsMenu`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openOptionsMenu%28%29) to show the options menu.

You should not invoke `onCreateOptionsMenu(…)` directly; this method is for the Android UI framework, not for you. If you need this method to be called *again*, for example, to refresh the menu items, you can call [`invalidateOptionsMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28%29) and Android will re-initialize the menu.

The same goes for `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem)`. If you need to make the app do something that normally happens when a particular menu item is selected, simply put that something in a separate method that you invoke from onOptionsItemSelected as well as from anywhere else you need it.